# ActionBarSherlock narrow items in ActionBar are not centered

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I'm using actionbarsherlock library, activity has flag android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow", so ActionBar's items are in the bottom of screen
the items are described in the xml file

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_0"
          android:title="@string/action_0"
          android:showAsAction="always"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_1"
          android:title="@string/action_1"
          android:showAsAction="always"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_2"
          android:title="@string/action_2"
          android:showAsAction="always"/>
</menu>
```

I'm inflating menu

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      menu.clear();
      MenuInflater supportMenuInflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
      supportMenuInflater.inflate(R.menu.inbox_conversation, menu);

  return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

after, on devices with android 2.3, menu items do not have the same weight
first two options take about 80% percents of action bar & the latest takes only 20%, so they are not aligned properly & don't take equal space. 
Don't know what to do. Any suggestions? 
Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

might want to try adding layout-weight in item tag in xml

```
<item 
    android:id="@+id/menu_0"
    android:title="@string/action_0"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_weight="1" >
</item>
```